# Merge vectorlayers and attributes in QGIS

Tags: qgis, algorithm

I am writing a script to run in QGIS and one thing I am trying to do is to merge a row of layers and their attributes. So if one layer is overlapping with another there should be created a new object with the attributes of both layers. I tried to do it with the "merge"-algorithm but its not working. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried running `merge` and then the SAGA-tool `selfintersection`?

Comment: Virtual layer is an option for you?

Comment: For some reason the SAGA-Tools aren't working. It alsways says no layer was created.

Comment: I havent worket with virtual layers yet but it could be a solution